# Split text from div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

```
<div id="qselected">
    <div class="qitem di ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
        2.A computational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.
    </div>
    <div class="qitem di ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
        4.A computational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
ans5 = $('#qselected div').map(function(){
    return this.class;
});
for(i=0; i < ans5.length; i++)
    alert(ans5[i]);
```

How do I get text from div id "qselected" and within the class "qitem" . I want to story all texts inside div's and div's.From the array arr[0] to 2.A computational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.similarly for arr[1] to 4.A computational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.Help me to get out of this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `.map()`, However What did you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in your code is that you are not accessing the correct property. there is no property as `class` thus it must be returning *undefined*

You need to return [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property in the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) along with `.get()` to get basic array.

```js
var arr = $('#qselected .qitem').map(function(key, item){
   return this.textContent.trim(); //$(this).text().trim();
}).get();
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qselected">
    <div class="qitem di ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
        2.A computational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.
    </div>
    <div class="qitem di ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
        4.A computational agent is considered intelligent if it can adapt its actions to a particular setting.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess Rory beat you by few seconds. :-p

Comment: @Rajesh, True, but see my comment. was egging OP to show his effort

Comment: I'd rather use `.text()` instead of `textContent`. Nothing wrong with either one but I like to keep my approach consistent. Just my POV

Comment: @Rajesh, why do need to create a jquery object when it can be directly fetched?

Comment: You are right. But as I mentioned, this is just my POV. In my experience, merging multiple approaches would add confusion in your code. Not going to make much difference here but in a large code base, it might.

Comment: @Satpal I normally would have done the same, but when I saw a poor answer was added I felt that I had to answer it correctly. I've deleted my answer and upvoted yours as you were first to comment with the correct approach

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I have not seen your when I hit the button otherwise I would not have posted it. You didn't need to delete your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have it done without using jquery

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.qitem')).map(function(a){return a.textContent});
```

Comment: `textContent` would serve better than `innerHTML`.